# How return to spring boot version 1.3.a

Tags: angularjs, jhipster

I created a new project with Jhipster.
The `.pom` file contains that the version of spring boot is `1.4.4`.
However, I want to use spring boot `1.3.0`.

How can I use an older version?

Comment: Have you tried changing version in your pom.xml ?

Comment: yes but it doesn't work